# 'ORA-00059: maximum number of files exceeded' on Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, linux, oracle-12c

I have a test database.  Every night a script drops and recreates a number of pluggable databases that are used for our automated test runs.  Recently, I have started getting 'ORA-00059: maximum number of files exceeded' errors on the create pluggable database commands.  I must be missing something, because from what I can tell, I am no where near the maximum (and this script was working a month ago).

```
SQL> select value from v$parameter where name = 'db_files';

VALUE
-----------------------------------------------------------

200

SQL> select count(*) from v$datafile;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        24

SQL> create pluggable database testdb FROM DB_SEED
  2    FILE_NAME_CONVERT = ('/home/ora12c1/app/ora12c1/oradata/ora12c1/testdb_seed/', '/home/ora12c1/app/ora12c1/oradata/ora12c1/testdb/')
  3    PATH_PREFIX = '/home/ora12c1/app/ora12c1/oradata/ora12c1/testdb';
create pluggable database testdb FROM DB_SEED
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00059: maximum number of DB_FILES exceeded
```

---

It looks like the following resolves the issue:
Bug 18522516  12.1.0.1.4 (Jul 2014) Database Patch Set Update (PSU)

One note though, I had to bounce the database before I could create a new pluggable database.  As, I preformed all the steps that I saw in the doc:

Apply the patch using opatch apply
Startup/Open all pdbs
Run datapatch -verbose

Then I had to bounce the database to resolve my issue.

Comment: This looks like a bug described in Doc ID 17461374.8.

Comment: @mutap, well then, I guess I am updating to 12.1.0.1.4.  Thanks for finding that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was posted as an update to the question:

> It looks like the following resolves the issue: Bug 18522516 12.1.0.1.4 (Jul 2014) Database Patch Set Update (PSU)
>
> One note though, I had to bounce the database before I could create a new pluggable database. As, I preformed all the steps that I saw in the doc:
>
> Apply the patch using opatch apply Startup/Open all pdbs Run datapatch -verbose
>
> Then I had to bounce the database to resolve my issue.